# Website is up and running but parsing it results in HTTP Error 503

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, urllib2, lxml

I want to crawl a webpage using urllib2 library and extract some information according to my need. I am able to freely navigate the site(going from one link to another and so on), but when I try to parse-it I am getting an error

```
HTTP Error 503 : Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

I searched about it on net and found out that this error occurs when "web site's server is not available at that time"

I am confused after reading this, if website server is down then how come its up and running(since I am able to navigate the webpage), and if the server is not down then why I am getting this 503 Error.

Is their a possibility that the server has done something to prevent the parsing of web-page

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your user-agent is banned from the server, so as to avoid, well, web crawlers. Therefore some websites, including Wikipedia, show up a 50x error when using an unwanted user-agent (such as wget, curl, urllib, …)

However, changing the user-agent might be enough. At least, it's the case for Wikipedia, which works just fine when using Firefox user agent. (The "bann" most probably only relies on the user-agent).

Finally, there must be a reason for those websites to ban web crawlers. Depending on what you're working on, you might want to use another solution. For example, wikipedia provides [database dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download), which can be convenient if you intend to make an intensive use of it.

PS. `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11` is the user-agent I use for wikipedia on a project of mine.

Comment: thanks for the tip, what about the time? is it ok for most servers to accept requests from the same device/useragent every 300ms or lower?

Comment: (assuming that server can handle that load and return result in less than 150ms)